# Unit Testing class which communicates with a database

Tags: c#, database, unit-testing

Ok Lets assume i have a class which controls my data layer and a class which performs the work.

```
class MyData
{
    public DataTable GetMyData()
    {
         return Query.MyDataBase.ResultDT();
    }
}

class MyWork
{
    public int DoWork()
    {
        MyData Data = new MyData();
        DataTable DT = Data.GetMyData();
        return DT.Rows.Count;
    }
}
```

How can i test my DoWork method with a unit test without accessing the database.

```
[TestMethod()]
public void TestMyWork()
{
    MyWork work = new MyWork();
    int result = work.DoWork();
    Assert.AreEqual(1, result);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the `MyData` class a dependency parameter and inject it during construction of your `MyWork` class. For unit testing purposes, mock the dependency in your unit test to ensure that it is calling the defined dependency's contract in an expected manner.

Typically this means:

- Defining an interface for the dependency i.e. IMyData
- The constructor signature should expect the interface type rather than the concrete type.

As a final result, your code would be transformed as follows:

```
interface IMyData
{
    DataTable GetMyData();
}

class MyData : IMyData
{
    public DataTable GetMyData()
    {
         return Query.MyDataBase.ResultDT();
    }
}

class MyWork
{
    private IMyData _myData;

    public MyWork(IMyData myData)
    {
        _myData = myData;
    }

    public int DoWork()
    {
        DataTable DT = _myData.GetMyData();
        return DT.Rows.Count;
    }
}
```

As a step further, you should check out the SOLID design principles as this type of design demonstrates why they exist.

More on [Wikipedia: SOLID (OO design)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))

**Edit:**

Your unit test would then look something like (assuming you're using the Moq mocking framework):

```
[TestMethod()]
public void TestMyWork()
{
    var mockMyData = Mock<IMyData>();
    mockMyData.Setup(x => x.GetMyData()).Returns(new DataTable());

    MyWork work = new MyWork(mockMyData);
    int result = work.DoWork();
    Assert.AreEqual(1, result);
}
```

..but in the real world you would more than likely instantiate `MyWork` with a real `MyData` instance as follows (unless you're using a Dependency Injection framework such as MEF or Unity):

```
var myWork = new MyWork(new MyData());
```

Answer (score 1):

First, follow @toadflakz advice and inject `MyData` to `MyWork`'s constructor.

Then, use some ORM to map the data from the db to objects. Don't use `DataTable`.

To make `DoWork` easier to test, consider refactoring it into a [pure function](http://www.sitepoint.com/functional-programming-pure-functions/):

```
public int DoWork(DataTable dt)
{
    // make some complex calculations on dt
}
```

This way the result of `DoWork` depends only on the input parameter, which makes it very easy to test.